# Timer Working for two times only , c# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have C# Console Application It's working just two times only .
when i use singleton pattern  to call my class and method  , i don't know where is the problem exactly in my code and also i use two One xml file to write and read data from it ,when i use external url service to read data , when i have only two c# classes :

Programe.cs , Tanks_Controller.cs

this my code i used it :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Xml;
using log4net;
using NHibernate;
using Configuration = NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration;

namespace Tank_Gauging.Franklin
{
    public class TankController
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log =
            LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        private static Timer aTimer;
        private static int tankCode;
        private static string WaterHeight { get; set; }
        private static string WaterVolume { get; set; }
        private static double ProductHeight { get; set; }
        private static double ProductVolume { get; set; }
        private static double Temperature { get; set; }
        private static double ProductTcVolume { get; set; }
        private static double ProductUllage { get; set; }
        static Timer _timer; // From System.Timers
        private NameValueCollection customConfig =
            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CustomConfiguration") as NameValueCollection;
        private static string _urlService = null;
        private Timer timer1;


        private static TankController instance;

        static int alarmCounter = 1;
        static bool exitFlag = false;

        private TankController()
        {
            //   init();
        }

        public static TankController Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new TankController();
                }

                <p> return</p>instance;
            }
        }

        public void init()
        {
            _urlService = customConfig["DemoUrlService"];
      //      onStart();
            Timer aTimer = new Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(getIntervialTimeIntervalTime());
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            getTankStatus();
            Log.Warn($@"Timer is set to : {e.SignalTime}");
        }

        private static bool getTankStatus()
        {

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            string responseStr = null;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(_urlService);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                "<TSA_REQUEST_LIST PASSWORD=''><TSA_REQUEST COMMAND=''/></TSA_REQUEST_LIST>"); // header request .
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=utf-8";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            }

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\user\tanks_data.xml", string.Empty); //  Remove everything in file .
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\user\tanks_data.xml", responseStr); // add new data response from service .


            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\user\tanks_data.xml"); // write data from xml file . 

            var counter = 1;

            var sessionFactory = new Configuration().BuildSessionFactory();
            var mySession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            var n = 1;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "TANK_STATUS")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"------------------------------ {counter} ----------------------------------");
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        /*reader.Name == "TANK_ID" */
                        if (reader.Name == "TANK_ID")
                        {
                            tankCode = Int32.Parse(reader.Value);
                            Log.Debug("TANK_ID = " + tankCode);
                        }

                        if (reader.Name == "WATER_LEVEL")
                        {
                            WaterHeight = reader.Value;
                            Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                            Log.Debug("WATER_LEVEL = " + WaterHeight);
                        }

                        if (reader.Name == "WATER_VOLUME")
                        {
                            WaterVolume = reader.Value; //Convert.ToDouble();
                            Log.Debug("WATER_VOLUME = " + WaterVolume);
                        }

                        if (reader.Name == "PRODUCT_LEVEL")
                        {
                            ProductHeight = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                            Log.Debug("WATER_VOLUME = " + WaterVolume);
                        }

                        if (reader.Name == "TEMPERATURE")
                        {
                            Temperature = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                            Log.Debug("TEMPERATURE = " + Temperature);
                        }

                        if (reader.Name == "ULLAGE_VOLUME")
                        {
                            ProductUllage = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                            Log.Debug("ULLAGE_VOLUME = " + ProductUllage);
                        }

                        if (reader.Name == "GROSS_PRODUCT_VOLUME")
                        {
                            ProductTcVolume = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                            Log.Debug("GROSS_PRODUCT_VOLUME = " + ProductTcVolume);
                        }

                        if (reader.Name == "NET_PRODUCT_VOLUME")
                        {
                            ProductVolume = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                            Log.Debug("NET_PRODUCT_VOLUME = " + ProductVolume);
                        }
                    }

                    counter++;

                    n++;
                    try
                    {
                        mySession.BeginTransaction();
                        mySession.CreateSQLQuery(
                                @" INSERT INTO GA_TANK_TRANSACTIONS (
                                    BRANCH_ID,
                                    WATER_VOLUME,
                                    ULLAGE_VOLUME,
                                    LIQUID_VOLUME,
                                      YEAR_CODE,
                                      SEQ,
                                      TRANS_DATE,
                                      TANK_CODE,
                                      WATER_HEIGHT,
                                      LIQUID_TEMPERATURE,
                                      TYPE_CODE,
                                      USER_ID,
                                      LIQUID_HEIGHT,
                                      LIQUID_MASS,
                                      LIQUID_DENSITY,
                                      LIQUID_TC_VOLUME,
                                      TRANS_HOUR,
                                      TRANS_MINUTE)
                        VALUES (:branchId,
                            (:waterVolume ),
                            :ullageVolume,
                            (:liquidVolume ),
                                :yearCode,
                                (SELECT NVL(MAX(SEQ), 0) + 1
                                 FROM GA_TANK_TRANSACTIONS
                                 WHERE BRANCH_ID = :branchId
                                   AND YEAR_CODE = :yearCode
                                   AND TYPE_CODE = 1066),
                                TRUNC(SYSDATE),
                                :tankCode,
                                (:waterHeight*1000),
                                :liquidTemperature,
                                1066,
                                NULL,
                                (:liquidHeight *1000),
                                :liquidMass,
                                :liquidDensity,
                                 :liquidTCVolume,
                                TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24')),
                                TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'mi')))")
                            .SetParameter("branchId", "1")
                            .SetParameter("tankCode", tankCode + "")
                            .SetParameter("yearCode", DateTime.Today.Year)
                            .SetParameter("waterHeight", WaterHeight)
                            .SetParameter("liquidMass", getLiquidMass(tankCode, ProductVolume))
                            .SetParameter("liquidHeight", ProductHeight)
                            .SetParameter("liquidTemperature", Temperature)
                            .SetParameter("liquidDensity", 0)
                            .SetParameter("liquidTCVolume", Temperature)
                            .SetParameter("waterVolume", WaterVolume)
                            .SetParameter("ullageVolume", ProductUllage)
                            .SetParameter("liquidVolume", ProductVolume)
                            .ExecuteUpdate();

                        mySession.Transaction.Commit();
                        mySession.Clear();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.Debug(e);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }


            Log.Debug("Successfully Commit Script .");



            return true;
        }

        private string getIntervialTimeIntervalTime()
        {
            try
            {
                var sessionFactory = new Configuration().BuildSessionFactory();
                var mySession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

                var probeTimeInterval =
                    mySession.CreateSQLQuery(
                            "SELECT NVL(GE_PKG.GET_GE_VALUE(1, 47, 313), 1) AS \"probeTimeInterval\" FROM dual")
                        .AddScalar("probeTimeInterval", NHibernateUtil.Int64)
                        .UniqueResult<long?>() * 100;
                Log.Debug($"Success Get Prop Interval Time {probeTimeInterval} sec ");
                return probeTimeInterval + "";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Debug(e);
                throw;
            }

            <p> return</p>null;
        }

        private static double getLiquidMass(int tankCode, double liquidVolume)
        {
            try
            {
                var sessionFactory = new Configuration().BuildSessionFactory();
                var mySession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
                var liquidMass =
                    mySession.CreateSQLQuery(
                            $@"SELECT NVL(FUEL_TYPE_DENSITY, 0)* NVL(:liquidVolume, 0) AS liquidMass
                         FROM GA_FUEL_TYPE
                         WHERE EXISTS(
                                 SELECT 1
                                 FROM GA_FUEL_TANKS
                                 WHERE GA_FUEL_TANKS.FUEL_CODE = GA_FUEL_TYPE.TYPE_CODE
                                   AND TANK_CODE = :tankCode
                                   AND BRANCH_ID = :branchId)"
                        )
                        .AddScalar("liquidMass", NHibernateUtil.Double)
                        .SetParameter("tankCode", tankCode)
                        .SetParameter("branchId", "1")
                        .SetParameter("liquidVolume", liquidVolume)
                        .UniqueResult<double>();
                Log.Debug($"Success Get Liquid Mass {liquidMass} ");
               <p> return</p> liquidMass;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Debug(e);
                throw;
            }

           <p> return</p> 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My Timer Code :

> ```
>            _urlService = customConfig["DemoUrlService"];
>       //      onStart();
>             Timer aTimer = new Timer();
>             aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
>             aTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(getIntervialTimeIntervalTime());
>             aTimer.AutoReset = true;
>             aTimer.Enabled = true;
> ```

Comment: Hi, could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?
Also: does this compile? You have a `private static Timer aTimer` in your `TankController` and in `TankController.init` method you declare a new Timer with same variable name: `Timer aTimer = new Timer();`. Maybe i just got confused from scrolling six pages? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cresting a LOCAL variable of your Timer, you should instead use your GLOBAL instance, like this:

```
    public void init()
    {
        _urlService = customConfig["DemoUrlService"];
  //      onStart();
        aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(getIntervialTimeIntervalTime());
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The problem, when you use a local Timer, is that when the method exits, the Timer get garbage collected and of course stops working.